# Buscar texto en una Ruta C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación `winform` para buscar un determinado texto dentro de una ruta de archivos.
**El problema** es que se **demora muchisimo** en algunas búsquedas y en ocasiones se cae. Sería conveniente si alguien me puede ayudar a **mejorar el rendimiento** del mismo, les comparto el código:

```
  private void btnexplorador_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtruta.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbxlista.Items.Clear();
            string ruta = @"" + txtruta.Text; //Escribir ruta
            string texto = txtfiltro.Text; //Escribir texto a buscar

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            //List<string> encontrados = new List<string>();
            foreach (string item in files)
            {
                string contenido = File.ReadAllText(item);

                if (contenido.Contains(texto))

                    lbxlista.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
```

Comment: y.. se va a demorar un monton, dependiendo de los archivos que estes abriendo. Para cosas asi se usan servicios de indices previos. Que es lo que tenes que hacer?

Comment: Tal cual dice @gbianchi todo depende de que tipos de archivos vas a recorrer. Si estos archivos son demasiado pesados, y contienen muchas lineas, tu código está cargando cada archivo por completo a memoria y lo filtra con el método `String.Contains`, quizás no sea la mejor forma para resolver tu problema.

Comment: estas realizando una busqueda secuencial en el contenido de archivos es seguro que va a demorar. Lo que si recomendaria es que solo levantas *.txt, y no solo el * ya que podria acceder a otras extrensiones que causen problemas por eso se caiga, igualmente deberias tener un try..catch en el codigo para poder ver cual es la causa de fallos. Pero la demora dudo que puedas solucionarlo, eso va a depender de que cantos archivos y que tan pesados sean

Answer (score 1):

Existe un método de `.NET Framework` que provee de esta funcionalidad. Dicho método es [Método FileSystem.FindInFiles (String, String, Boolean, SearchOption)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.findinfiles?view=netframework-4.7.1). Bien es cierto que este método se encuentra en el espacio de nombres `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` en el ensamblado `Microsoft.VisualBasic (en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)`. La implementación en C# sería algo así:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a list of files based on filename-with-wildcard search criteria and file-content search criteria.
/// Regular expressions are not supported (yet).
/// Calls System.IO.Directory.GetFiles to get files.
/// Calls System.IO.File.ReadAllText().Contains to search contents.
/// Uses ToLower() to perform case-insensitive search.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="directoryArg">Directory to start search, such as @"C:\" or Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot")</param>
/// <param name="containsTextArg">Test to search for. "" will be found in any file.</param>
/// <param name="ignoreCaseArg"></param>
/// <param name="searchSubDirsArg"></param>
/// <param name="fileWildcardsArg">Can be an array of files or a single file such as "*.ini"</param>
/// <returns>a list of files (complete paths) found.</returns>
static IEnumerable<string> FindInFiles( 
    string                 directoryArg,
    string                 containsTextArg,
    bool                   ignoreCaseArg,
    System.IO.SearchOption searchSubDirsArg,
    params string[]        fileWildcardsArg )
{

    IEnumerable<string> files =
        from fileWildcard in fileWildcardsArg
        from file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryArg, fileWildcard, searchSubDirsArg)
        where
            containsTextArg.Length == 0 ||
            ignoreCaseArg ?
            System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file).ToLower().Contains(containsTextArg.ToLower()) :
            System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file).Contains(containsTextArg)
        select file;

    return files;
}
```

Y un ejemplo de llamada sería el siguiente:

```
IEnumerable oemFiles = FindInFiles( Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"), "VID_08b1", false, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories, "OEM*.INF" );
```